# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'StringConstructor'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a dictionary using a loop as below

```
var productList = []

for (var product  of order.products) {
    var productData = {Image: String, Description: String, Price: String};

    const url: String = `<img src="${product.image}" alt="${product.title}">`;

    productData['Image'] = `<img src="${product.image}" alt="${product.title}">`;
    productData['Image'] = url

    productData['Description'] = product.description
    productData['Price'] = product.salePrice

    productList.push(productData);

}
```

so I'm going to build a `html img` tag as a **string** by contacting parameters from the product

I tried by changing parameter types, and based on other StackOverflow answers

but all time I'm getting a below error for  `productData['Image']`

so still, I couldn't fix the error or get understand about `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'StringConstructor'`

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either assign an anonymous object to a variable or indicate a type and assign a value:

```
const productData: { Image: string, Description: string, Price: string } = { Image: '', Description: '', Price: '' };
```

OR

```
const productData = { Image: '', Description: '', Price: '' };
```

Comment: it works thank you, can you please explain what is the logic or theory behind this

Comment: You tried to assign an object with types as values to a variable instead of indicating a type or assign an object with all necessary fields.